# Slick Slider Move Pagination Above Slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am initializing my slider like so

**JS**

```
$('.responsive-slider').slick({
  nextArrow: '<span class="slick-divider right"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
  prevArrow: '<span class="slick-divider left"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 6,
  slidesToScroll: 6,
});
```

**PHP**

```
<div class="responsive-slider feat-slider-container">
  <?php foreach ($products as $i => $product) { $i=$i+1; ?>
  <div class="slide" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="overlay__container relative">
      <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name'];?>">
        <img
        src="<?php $product['thumb'] = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/gd\d.alicdn.com)/', 'https://img.alicdn.com', $product['thumb']); echo $product['thumb']; ?>"
        itemprop="image"
        alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"
        title="<?php echo $product['name'];?>"
        class="img-responsive" />
        <span itemprop="name" class="slider--name" title="<?php echo $product['name'];?>"><?php echo $product['pname']; ?></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide__caption">
      <div class="price">
        <span><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="responsive-slider feat-slider-container slick-initialized slick-slider" role="toolbar"><span class="slick-divider left slick-arrow slick-disabled" aria-disabled="true" style="display: block;"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left slick-arrow slick-disabled" aria-disabled="true" style="display: block;"></i>
    <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
        <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 4368px; left: 0px;" role="listbox">
            <div class="slide slick-slide" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" data-slick-index="9" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 172px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide19">
                <div class="overlay__container relative">
                    <a href="http://www.baopals.com:3000/products/37436993683" title="Jiuchuan Bamboo Bookshelves" tabindex="-1">
                        <img src="http://example.com" itemprop="image" alt="J" title="" class="img-responsive">
                        <span itemprop="name" class="slider--name" title="Jiuchuan Bamboo Bookshelves">example</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide__caption">
                    <div class="price">
                        <span>￥xx.xx</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="slick-divider right slick-arrow" style="display: block;" aria-disabled="false"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right slick-arrow" style="display: block;" aria-disabled="false"></i>
    <ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;" role="tablist">
        <li class="slick-active" aria-hidden="false" role="presentation" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="navigation10" id="slick-slide10">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">1</button>
        </li>
        <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation11" id="slick-slide11">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">2</button>
        </li>
        <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation12" id="slick-slide12">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">3</button>
        </li>
        <li aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="navigation13" id="slick-slide13">
            <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" aria-required="false" tabindex="0">4</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There is 4 sliders on the same page. how do I get the pagination correlated to the correct slider above the slides instead of below?

Comment: Can you post the actual html generated by PHP?

Comment: @AlbertIsrael added example html

Answer (score 5):

There's an option in Slick called **appendDots** where you can append the dots navigation to any element in your page. So you may try to create an element above your slider then use this element in your Slick instance:

```
$('.responsive-slider').slick({
  nextArrow: '<span class="slick-divider right"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
  prevArrow: '<span class="slick-divider left"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  appendDots: $('element-to-append-dots-nav'),
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 6,
  slidesToScroll: 6,
});
```

Try if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.slick-dots{
   bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: Im looking for a way to render html of the pagination above the slides them selves css wont work for me in this situation

Comment: I think pagination added dynamically by slick js. So you need to add css to position to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with the following each loop to `prepend` to my sliders

```
$( ".responsive-slider" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).prepend( $(this).find($( ".slick-dots" )));
});
```